# Is it possible to run pg_rewind without shutdown the database?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

Is it possible to run pg_rewind without shutting down the database?

I have started postgres service as PID 1 so when I'm stop (using pg_ctl stop)the db docker, PG container is also be stop and I have to run `docker  exec -it dockername /bin/sh` to start again.

How can I sync datafiles after failover/failback. Method of use pg_rewind without restarting container.

Answer (score 1):

You need the current-master running because pg_rewind does need a database connection through 5432 or any other database port you have. But the target node has to be stopped because we are changing all the datafiles in a physical way using pg_rewind.